# XcodeColors not working in XCode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, logging, plugins

I tried to install `XcodeColors` in XCode 5. But unfortunately it isn't working with the old plugin I got from XCode 4.6.

As next step, I checked the github website where i saw the following pull request providing a working version for XCode 5:
https://github.com/mralexgray/XcodeColors

I have downloaded the project and run it in release mode. But there isn't any `XcodeColors` created in the plugin directory.

Does anybody have a working `XcodeColors` Plugin in XCode 5?

Comment: Its also not working for me. Anyone has a solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has been fixed : you will find [here](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XcodeColors) all the procedure to install `XcodeColors` for `Xcode5`. You'll need to download the sources, and to compile it on your computer. It will automatically install the right file at the right place.

Comment: Have you verified whether or not this works in the 5.1 prerelease?

Comment: Once the XcodeColors plugin is installed with XCode 5.1 Release, it crashes upon 'Run'.

Comment: @SebastianDwornik same here! Anyone?