# Xcode Plugins Stopped Working

Tags: xcode, plugins, xcode5, xcode6

[Dave Keck's `Fixins`](https://github.com/davekeck/Xcode-4-Fixins) stopped working on Xcode. I've already tried rebuilding with no avail. Anybody found a workaround? (I'm mostly longing for `CurrentLineHighlighter` and `DisableAnimations`.)

Related question on another plugin: [XcodeColors not working in XCode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970490/xcodecolors-not-working-in-xcode-5)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I've written [a longer answer on how to automate upgrading these plugins, Xcode 8 included](https://merela.org/automate-xcode-upgrades.html).

---

You can get some<sup>*</sup> plugins to work with Xcode 5 by adding a `DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs` array into each plugin's `Info.plist`. Then add a UUID string to this array.

```
<key>DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs</key>
<array>
    <string>37B30044-3B14-46BA-ABAA-F01000C27B63</string>
</array>
```

To get the UUID, execute `defaults read /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID` in console.

<sup>*</sup> E.g. `DisableAnimations` and `HideDistractions` work, while `CurrentLineHighlighter` invariably crashes Xcode.

Comment: I haven't been able to get DisableAnimations to work as it crashes Xcode on launch using the new UUID in Xcode 5.1 (5B130a).  This is the code I used:      <key>DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs</key>
 <array>
  <string>A2E4D43F-41F4-4FB9-BB94-7177011C9AED</string>
 </array>`

Comment: Excellent. fyi only - this is still working with XCode 7.2.

Answer (score 23):

**EDIT:** Starting with Xcode 8, the plugins system doesn't work anymore, [more information](https://github.com/alcatraz/Alcatraz/issues/475). This answer won't work for Xcode 8 and later.

---

**Original answer:**

Xcode's plugins stopped working after each update. In order to fix them all quickly, you can use the following command line in your terminal. That will update each plugin and make them compatible with the new update.

```
find ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins -name Info.plist -maxdepth 3 | xargs -I{} defaults write {} DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs -array-add `defaults read /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID`
```

**Note:** You have to restart Xcode in order to have your plugins work again

**Note 2:** You will have to run this command for each Xcode update

Comment: This solution has a slight edge over the accepted one. Pasted it into an Automator app and now it's just `⌘-Space` + `fix` to quickly reset Xcode after each update! Brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

You can find simple solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24427098/2066428)

You should use another plugins folder

```
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns
```