# Plugins not working in XCode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, plugins, xcode5

Just installed XCode 5. Previously some popular plugins for Xcode. those plugins was working for xcode 4.5. But after upgrading to xcode 5 none of the plugins are working. I have freshly downloaded plugins like VVDocumenter, KSImageNamed etc.But its not getting any advantage. Also tried https://github.com/mneorr/Alcatraz Its also not doing anything

Comment: Plugins will need to be updated for Xcode 5, either get the code and do it your self or wait until the developer updates there plugin.

Comment: but here https://github.com/mneorr/Alcatraz says its working for Xcode 5 GM

Comment: I cant find any where on the page you linked to that it works whit Xcode 5. There is a merge request for Xcode 5: https://github.com/mneorr/Alcatraz/pull/74 you might want to try that one.

Answer (score 0):

xCode 5 uses another plugins folder by default

```
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns
```

Try to put your plugins there.

But note that for example KSImageNamed.xcplugin and Lin.xcplugin
cause crashes of the xCode 5.1 at least.